# Devise remove a user but keep his data, and set a flag _is_deleted in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I would like to delete a user with devise but be able to save its data just setting a flag like is_deleted to true and prevent login for those users.

What would be the best way to do this in devise ? I have seen some write-ups on this but they were for rails 2.x projects, Im on rails 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set that deleted flag normally then override the `find_for_authentication` class level method in the user model.

The following should work

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions) 
  super(conditions.merge(:is_deleted => false))
end
```

Comment: How about you want to have a deleted_at and store the date time when a user deleted its account? That would be better i mistakenly formulated my question with is_deleted but need a deleted_at field and on delete save that date time in user table.

Comment: If the timestamp defaults to nil when the user isn't deleted you could change the condition merge to `conditions.merge(:deleted_at => nil)`

Comment: I'm not having luck with `conditions.merge(:deleted_at => nil)`.  Adding that causes devise to not let anyone log in.  I suspect it's related to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/plataformatec-devise/Pv5xAWlYtvM/IUoM1AtB6y8J I guess I'll just switch to a boolean field to work around it.

Comment: Anyone who not working with nil, please refer here https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/2186#issuecomment-11919436

Answer (score 5):

If you want to prevent sign_in users whose deleted_at fields are not null, override [active_for_authentication?](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L87) on your devise resource model:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && !deleted_at
end
```

Comment: This will cause Devise to state `Your account is not activated yet.` instead of `Invalid email or password.` (which is reflected by the accepted answer to this question). Not necessarily good or bad either way, but there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a default scope on your model.
Define a state on your User model, and add a default scope (Rails 3), this will scope all the queries on the User model with the condition from the scope:

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope where("state  != 'disabled'")

  def disable!
    self.update_attribute(:state, 'disabled')
  end

end
```

Then, over-write the *destroy* method in your session controller, make sure you to grab the destroy code from the version of devise you're using:

*app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb*

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # paranoid DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    resource.disable! # we don't remove the record with resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_navigational_format?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end

end
```

You can take it a step further by defining a state machine on your User model (be careful of how this will not cascade down the dependency tree, like a `:dependent => :destroy` would):

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
include ActiveRecord::Transitions

  state_machine do
    state :passive
    state :active
    state :disabled, :enter => :bye_bye_user

    event :activate do
      transitions :from => :passive, :to => :active
    end
    event :disable do
      transitions :from => [:passive,:active], :to => :disabled
    end
  end

  default_scope where("state  != 'disabled'")

end
```

Answer (score 0):

@dgmdan: In regards to using :deleted_at => nil instead of false:

Devise's [`find_for_authentication`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L241) method runs the conditions through a [filter which stringifies values](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/param_filter.rb#L30).  What's happening is that the `nil` value being passed in for `deleted_at` is being converted to an empty string.  This makes the query match no one, and thus to the end user it looks like the username and password were incorrect.

`find_for_authentication` calls [`find_first_by_auth_conditions`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L245) like this:

```
def find_for_authentication(tainted_conditions)
  find_first_by_auth_conditions(tainted_conditions)
end
```

[Per the author](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2412), `find_first_by_auth_conditions` takes an optional second parameter, another conditions hash, but this one does *not* go through the filter.  So what you can do is change the method like this:

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions)
  find_first_by_auth_conditions(conditions, {:deleted_at => nil})
end
```

The second conditions hash with the `:deleted_at => nil` should be passed straight through to the ORM layer.